# How to stop my XML file from being truncated when I try and parse the file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xml-parsing

I am getting the below error when my program tries to read from an XML config file:

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/sara/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PoseidonWebserviceWAR_v12/config.xml; lineNumber: 74; columnNumber: 20; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.**

After a bit a reading, I am fairly certain that this is because the parser is truncating my XML file, causing the program to believe I don't have well-formed XML. But, I am at a major loss on to go about debugging this problem as I am new to web-projects like the one I am making.

Another oddity: My web-project has been working well for several weeks now just fine, but now all of a sudden I get this error? Can anyone explain this?

The below code is is from a class where I define my XML read/write operations:

```
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc;
...
public XMLReader(String filePath){

      try {
          String f = filePath;
          xmlFile = new File(filePath);
          builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
          doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
```

...In another class I want to set the element "LastCurrentState" to 1234, but since the XML file was truncated, my reader is unable to read the file and here and error is where the error is thrown:

```
XMLReader xmlread = new XMLReader(filepath);
xmlread.setNameofNode(0, "LastCurrentState", 1234);
```

Again, these methods have been working fine for awhile, but now all of a sudden the file is being truncated.  What could be causing this?

----UPDATE---- here is my XML file code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Config>
<Sources>
    <Source> 
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Name>Dish1</Name>                  
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>2</Number>
        <Name>Dish2</Name>
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>3</Number>
        <Name>Sky1</Name>
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>4</Number>
        <Name>Sky2</Name>
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>5</Number>
        <Name>Sky3</Name>
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>6</Number>
        <Name>Sky4</Name>
    </Source>   
    <Source> 
        <Number>7</Number>
        <Name>Source7</Name>
    </Source>
    <Source> 
        <Number>8</Number>
        <Name>Source8</Name>
    </Source>
</Sources>  
<Targets>
    <Target>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Name>Corner - TV1</Name>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <Number>2</Number>
        <Name>Left - TV2</Name>
    </Target>       
    <Target>
        <Number>3</Number>
        <Name>Main - TV3</Name>
    </Target>   
    <Target>
        <Number>4</Number>
        <Name>Right - TV4</Name>
    </Target>   
    <Target>
        <Number>5</Number>
        <Name>Office - TV5</Name>
    </Target>   
    <Target>
        <Number>6</Number>
        <Name>Bar - TV6</Name>
    </Target>   
    <Target>
        <Number>7</Number>
        <Name>Outside - TV7</Name>
    </Target>   
    <Target>
        <Number>8</Number>
        <Name>Downstairs - TV8</Name>
    </Target>           
</Targets>

<Properties>
    <LastCurrentState>EE11111111</LastCurrentState>
    <DeviceName>KeyDigitalMSW</DeviceName>
    <SerialPortName>/dev/ttyS0</SerialPortName>
</Properties>
```

Comment: What does your xml look like?

Comment: Is the XML Editor not complaining about the contents?

Comment: This sounds like your XML file is not `well formed`. We need to see the XML

Comment: UPDATE: The editor is not complaining, and I checked it using W3 schools XML Validator. I  can post code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you show us is not well formed. There's no  `</Config>` end-tag at the end of the file. Add one.